# hay versiones de flutter para 32bit o solo 64bist?

Tags: flutter

busque en varios sitios y no tengo claro si hay versión de 32bits, y si hay alguna forma de instalarlo en mi maquina de 32bits.
esto es lo que me dice el cmd:
C:\flutter>flutter doctor
Esta versión de C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe no es compatible con la versión de Windows que está ejecutando. Compruebe la información de sistema del equipo y después póngase en contacto con el anunciante de software.

Comment: Segun la documentación del Github si, [flutter](https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/src/images/homepage/dart-diagram-small.png).

Comment: para Que versión de windows es?

Comment: Ya vi la de [descarga de windows](https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/src/images/homepage/dart-diagram-small.png) y es necesario 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

No, no existe. En 2019 se abrio una solicitud en [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33862) y lamentablemente el tren de desarrollo ya declaro obsoleto 32 bit. Android Studio ya no soporta 32 bit desde 2019 y flutter se apoya en eso. Teoricamente se podria lograr pero es muchisimo trabajo y solo aumentaria el tamaño de flutter y tambien la cantidad de posibles errores.